# How to update favorite status bool (true/false) in the JSON local file once the favorite button is toggled in the Flutter app

Tags: flutter, favorites

How to update favorite status bool (true/false) in the JSON local file once the favorite button is toggled in the Flutter app.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: Thanks I tried it, but still doesn’t working :(